# Oracle date as fraction of month

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

I would like to get a table of months between two dates with a fraction of each month that the two dates cover.

For example with a start date of 15/01/2017 and end date of 01/03/2017 it would output:

```
01/2017 : 0.5483..
02/2017 : 1
03/2017: 0.0322..
```

where for January and March the calculations are 17/31 and 1/31 respectively. I currently have the query:

```
WITH dates_between as (SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(TO_DATE(:givenStartDate,'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'MON'), ROWNUM - 1) date_out
                    FROM   DUAL
                    CONNECT BY ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(TO_DATE(:givenStartDate,'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'MON'), ROWNUM - 1)
                        <= TRUNC(TO_DATE(:givenEndDate,'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'MON')
)

select * from dates_between
```

This outputs each month between two dates and formats it to the start of the month. I just need another column to give me the fraction the start and end dates cover. I'm not sure of a way to do this without it getting messy.

Comment: Sometimes it is really simple: [MONTHS_BETWEEN](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions114.htm#SQLRF00669)

Comment: 1 problem in your logic. If for march, your percentage is `1/31`, then for Jan, shouldn't it be `15/31` rather than `16/31`?

Comment: It's the percentage within the range, as the 15/01/17 is the start date there are 16 more days left in the month. For march 01/03/17 is the end date so there is only 1 day is covered for march.

Comment: So the starting date isn't included in the range? 15th-31st Jan is 17 days if it's inclusive. If the range started on 31/01/2017 you would show 0 for the fraction? Also, what if the range went to April; should one day in April be 1/30 or 1/31 (as `months_between` would give you)?

Comment: Ahh yeah thanks for pointing that out, I overlooked that - it is inclusive. I'll update the question. So if the range started on the 31st it would be 1/31 of the month. Ideally it would be the days in the month so for april it would be 1/30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`months_between()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions114.htm) "calculates the fractional portion of the result based on a 31-day month". That means that if your range starts or ends in a month that doesn't have 31 days, the fraction you get might not be quite what you expect:

```
select months_between(date '2017-04-02', date '2017-04-01') as calc from dual

      CALC
----------
.0322580645
```

... which is 1/31, not 1/30. To get 0.0333... instead you'd need to calculate the number of days in each month, at least for the first and last month. This uses a recursive CTE (11gR2+) to get the months, using a couple of date ranges provided by another CTE as a demo to show the difference (you can use a hierarchical query too of course):

```
with ranges (id, start_date, end_date) as (
  select 1, date '2017-01-15', date '2017-03-01' from dual
  union all select 2, date '2017-01-31', date '2017-03-01' from dual
  union all select 3, date '2017-02-28', date '2017-04-01' from dual
),
months (id, month_start, month_days, range_start, range_end) as (
  select id,
    trunc(start_date, 'MM'),
    extract(day from last_day(start_date)),
    start_date,
    end_date
  from ranges
  union all
  select id,
    month_start + interval '1' month,
    extract(day from last_day(month_start + interval '1' month)),
    range_start,
    range_end
  from months
  where month_start < range_end
)
select id,
  to_char(month_start, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as month_start,
  month_days,
  case when month_start = trunc(range_start, 'MM')
      then month_days - extract(day from range_start) + 1
    when month_start = trunc(range_end, 'MM')
      then extract(day from range_end)
    else month_days end as range_days,
  (case when month_start = trunc(range_start, 'MM')
      then month_days - extract(day from range_start) + 1
    when month_start = trunc(range_end, 'MM')
      then extract(day from range_end)
    else month_days end) / month_days as fraction
from months
order by id, month_start;
```

which gets:

```
    ID MONTH_STAR MONTH_DAYS RANGE_DAYS FRACTION
------ ---------- ---------- ---------- --------
     1 2017-01-01         31         17   0.5483
     1 2017-02-01         28         28        1
     1 2017-03-01         31          1   0.0322
     2 2017-01-01         31          1   0.0322
     2 2017-02-01         28         28        1
     2 2017-03-01         31          1   0.0322
     3 2017-02-01         28          1   0.0357
     3 2017-03-01         31         31        1
     3 2017-04-01         30          1   0.0333
```

The first CTE `ranges` is just the demo data. The second, recursive, CTE `months` generates the start and number of days in each month, while keeping track of the original range dates too. The final query just calculates the fractions based on the number of days in the month in the range against the number of days in that month overall.

The `month_days` and `range_days` are only shown in the output so you can see what the calculation is based on, you can obviously omit those from your actual result, and format the month start date however you want.

With your original single pair of bind variables the equivalent would be:

```
with months (month_start, month_days, range_start, range_end) as (
  select trunc(to_date(:givenstartdate, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'MM'),
    extract(day from last_day(to_date(:givenstartdate, 'DD/MM/YYYY'))),
    to_date(:givenstartdate, 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
    to_date(:givenenddate, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
  from dual
  union all
  select month_start + interval '1' month,
    extract(day from last_day(month_start + interval '1' month)),
    range_start,
    range_end
  from months
  where month_start < range_end
)
select to_char(month_start, 'MM/YYYY') as month,
  (case when month_start = trunc(range_start, 'MM')
      then month_days - extract(day from range_start) + 1
    when month_start = trunc(range_end, 'MM')
      then extract(day from range_end)
    else month_days end) / month_days as fraction
from months
order by month_start;

MONTH   FRACTION
------- --------
01/2017   0.5483
02/2017        1
03/2017   0.0322
```

Comment: As you've pointed out, months_between can't really be used for a complete solution to this. Shame it can't be simpler. Works great though, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it (n.b. I have expanded your dates_between to work against multiple rows, purely for demonstration purposes. If you're only working with a single set of parameters, you wouldn't need to do that):

```
WITH        params AS (SELECT 1 ID, '15/01/2017' givenstartdate, '01/03/2017' givenenddate FROM dual UNION ALL
                       SELECT 2 ID, '15/01/2017' givenstartdate, '23/01/2017' givenenddate FROM dual UNION ALL
                       SELECT 3 ID, '01/01/2017' givenstartdate, '07/04/2017' givenenddate FROM dual),
     dates_between AS (SELECT ID,
                              to_date(givenstartdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy') givenstartdate,
                              to_date(givenenddate, 'dd/mm/yyyy') givenenddate,
                              add_months(trunc(to_date(givenstartdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'MON'), LEVEL - 1) start_of_month,
                              last_day(add_months(trunc(to_date(givenstartdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'MON'), LEVEL - 1)) end_of_month
                       FROM   params
                       CONNECT BY add_months(trunc(to_date(givenstartdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'MON'),  LEVEL - 1) <=
                                  trunc(to_date(givenenddate, 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'MON')
                                  AND PRIOR ID = ID
                                  AND PRIOR sys_guid() IS NOT NULL)
SELECT ID,
       givenstartdate,
       givenenddate,
       start_of_month date_out,
       end_of_month,
       months_between(LEAST(givenenddate, end_of_month) + 1, GREATEST(start_of_month, givenstartdate))
FROM   dates_between;

    ID GIVENSTARTDATE GIVENENDDATE DATE_OUT   END_OF_MONTH       DIFF
```

---

```
     1 15/01/2017     01/03/2017   01/01/2017 31/01/2017   0.54838709
     1 15/01/2017     01/03/2017   01/02/2017 28/02/2017            1
     1 15/01/2017     01/03/2017   01/03/2017 31/03/2017   0.03225806
     2 15/01/2017     23/01/2017   01/01/2017 31/01/2017   0.29032258
     3 01/01/2017     07/04/2017   01/01/2017 31/01/2017            1
     3 01/01/2017     07/04/2017   01/02/2017 28/02/2017            1
     3 01/01/2017     07/04/2017   01/03/2017 31/03/2017            1
     3 01/01/2017     07/04/2017   01/04/2017 30/04/2017   0.22580645
```

N.B. You may need to add a case statement to decide whether you want to add 1 or not to the diff calculation, based on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

For first month, I have calculated `remaining days / total days` and for last month, I subtracted it by `1` to get `days passed / total days`.

<kbd>**[`DBFiddle Demo`](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5f3ca36a2b22bed217ea1f9409443ef5)**</kbd>

```
WITH tbl AS
  (SELECT date '2017-01-15' AS givenStartDate 
        ,date '2017-03-01' AS givenEndDate
   FROM dual
   )
SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(givenStartDate, 'MON'), ROWNUM - 1) AS date_out ,
       CASE
        WHEN 
        rownum - 1 = 0 
            THEN months_between(last_day(givenStartDate), givenStartDate)

        WHEN ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(givenStartDate, 'MON'), ROWNUM - 1) = TRUNC(givenEndDate, 'MON') 
            THEN 1 - (months_between(last_day(givenEndDate), givenEndDate))

        ELSE 1
       END AS perc
FROM tbl 
CONNECT BY ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(givenStartDate, 'MON'), ROWNUM - 1) 
    <= TRUNC(givenEndDate, 'MON');
```

Output

```
+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
| DATE_OUT  |                   PERC                    |
+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
| 01-JAN-17 | .5161290322580645161290322580645161290323 |
| 01-FEB-17 |                                         1 |
| 01-MAR-17 | .0322580645161290322580645161290322580645 |
+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
```